# ListView with multiple elements (image view) overlapping

Tags: android, android-listview

Got into confusion I have to do book shelf for tablet. Which holds books in the row. So i planed to use list view. I dont want to do in grid view because the background image was not getting scrollable with the item. So i was running out of time. So thought to use list view. I am able to show books in the shelf. But the images of the book in the shelf are getting overlapped. Please help me to resolve this. Any help is very much valuable to me.

Code is bit lengthy, and its just like other list view. So i guess it is comming from getview method. So you can check that part directly. Rest of the code is for your reference
And also please observe the snapshot which is attached.

Please check the below code :

```
/*
 * Number of books in array - totalBooks
 * To display number of books in one row - bookItem
 * Quotient (Number of rows will hold books) -  numberOfBookRows
 * Reminder (Number of extra books in row) - extraBooks  
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BookShelf extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Book-shelf";
    //calculation
    private int totalBooks = 0;
    private int bookItem = 0;
    private int numberOfBookRows = 0;
    private int extraBooks = 0;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView listview;

    private String[] bookName = new String[5];
    private int[] bookImage = new int[5];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_shelf);

        // THIS ARE STATIC CONTENT

        // Title of book
        bookName[0] = "EMF";
        bookName[1] = "Ganddhi";
        bookName[2] = "The Code";
        bookName[3] = "The Code";
        bookName[4] = "The Code";

        // Image for book
        bookImage[0] = R.drawable.book1;
        bookImage[1] = R.drawable.book2;
        bookImage[2] = R.drawable.book3;
        bookImage[3] = R.drawable.book3;
        bookImage[4] = R.drawable.book1;

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        calculateRowsAndColms();
        adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(BookShelf.this, R.layout.book_shelf_row);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        addEmptyRow(5);
    }

    public void calculateRowsAndColms(){
        totalBooks = 0;
        bookItem = 0;
        numberOfBookRows = 0;
        extraBooks = 0;

        totalBooks = bookName.length;
        bookItem = 3;//TODO: make it dynamic
        if(totalBooks < bookItem && totalBooks > 0){
            numberOfBookRows = 1;
        }else{
            numberOfBookRows = (totalBooks/bookItem);
            extraBooks = (totalBooks % bookItem);
            if( extraBooks != 0)
                 numberOfBookRows++;
        }

        Log.d(TAG," Total books:"+totalBooks);
        Log.d(TAG," Number of books to be displayed:"+bookItem);
        Log.d(TAG," Number of rows occupying the books:"+numberOfBookRows);
        Log.d(TAG," Number of extra books(odd count):"+extraBooks);
    }

    public void addEmptyRow(int count) {

        LinearLayout ll_addRows = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.add_rows);
        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        count = count * 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            ImageView bg = new ImageView(this);
            bg.setImageResource(R.drawable.book_shelf_bgdub);
            bg.setLayoutParams(params);
            bg.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            ImageView border = new ImageView(this);
            border.setImageResource(R.drawable.book_shelf_border_dub);
            border.setLayoutParams(params);
            border.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            Log.d(TAG, "i:" + i);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                ll_addRows.addView(bg, i);
            else
                ll_addRows.addView(border, i);
            Log.d(TAG, "i:" + i);
        }
    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        Context context;
        int rowXmlId;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            rowXmlId = textViewResourceId;
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return numberOfBookRows;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d(TAG, " POSITION:" + position);

            ViewHolder holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(rowXmlId, null, false);

                ImageView image1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image1);
                ImageView image2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image2);
                ImageView image3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image3);

                holder.imgList.add(image1);
                holder.imgList.add(image2);
                holder.imgList.add(image3);
                v.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }


            if( (position == numberOfBookRows-1) &&  extraBooks!=0)
                for(int i=0; i<extraBooks; i++){ 
                    int k = (position * bookItem)+i;
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setBackgroundResource(bookImage[k]);
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnBookClickListner());
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setId(k);

                    Log.d(TAG,"============> k:"+k+" i:"+i+" id:"+holder.imgList.get(i).getId());
                }
            else
                for(int i=0; i<bookItem; i++){
                    int k = (position * bookItem)+i;
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setBackgroundResource(bookImage[k]);
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new OnBookClickListner());
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.imgList.get(i).setId(k);

                    Log.d(TAG,"============> k:"+k+" i:"+i+" id:"+holder.imgList.get(i).getId());
                }

            return v;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ArrayList<ImageView> imgList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        //ImageView image1, image2 ,image3;
    }

    public class OnBookClickListner implements OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, " ITEM SELECTED IN LIST VIEW:"+v.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(BookShelf.this, MyLessons.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

The xml is attached as follows: book_shelf.xml
This is the main xml which has list and adding some border for book shelf in stating and beginning of list. Nothing much is done here. Just using the list from this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/book_shelf_top_border" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/book_shelf_border_dub" >
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/book_shelf_border_dub" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_rows"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

The below xml book_shelf_row.xml
This xml i am using to represent a row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/book_shelf_bgdub"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/book1"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/book2"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/book3"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Each image view will hold the image of the book.

Below is the snapshot. How book images are getting overlapped.
[image: the image is over lapping on each other]

The R.drawable.book1 to book3 can be seen in the image respectively. 
In the first row it self images are getting replaced as well as second row.
If you observe the image deeply. The first image in first row. Is overlapped twice.
I am not understanding why is this happening. Can you help me on this please.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok got the problem resolved. 
In book_shelf_row.xml The imageview is having background image. So the images were overlapping 
when it come to do dynamically.

conclusion: remove the src attribute from imageview. Since we are dynamically changing the src attribute in code.